# Can I have multiple instances of the same component using a Lightning Message Service channel?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service, lightning-message-channel

If I create an lwc app component that uses an LMS message channel, will I run into problems if I have multiple instances of that app in a record page?

By problems, I mean all instances of the component attempting to handle the message from one instance of the component.

If that is the case, what can be done about it?

Comment: This is kind of an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Every subscriber to a LMS will receive a copy of it when publishing to that channel, anywhere in the DOM. As such, if you need to prevent this from happening, you'll have to do so somehow. However, without knowing what you're trying to do (your X problem), I don't feel like I can write a sufficiently accurate answer to your problem.

Comment: I suppose the "X" is that I'd like to use LMS in my widget because it's convenient, but I've been warned that it is problematic when there are multiple instances of said widget in the DOM. 

I haven't yet tested such a scenario. I'm only at the stage of imagining it and attempting to find out if others have encountered it. 

If my widget shows a spinner on a button click, requests data, and then hides the spinner when a response is returned, would all instances of my widget in the DOM show their spinners, etc.?

Thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: Your concerns are well-founded. In the example you gave, every spinner would indeed activate. There are alternatives, but without being more specific, it's hard to tell what advice to give. It could be either a public method on the child, a public property, or perhaps an advanced implementation using a modified pubsub model or generated ID values. The more information you can provide specifically, the better a solution we can suggest.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if a solution to those concerns wouldn't be to have the parent component generate a unique hash at runtime and then call a method (setter?) on each child that will use the LMS channel in its renderedCallback to supply them with the hash. Then, when the child publishes an event, they can pass the hash along with it which could then be checked for equality by the handler. When another instance of the same component inevitably handles the event, the hash won't be equal and so it can disregard the message. Again, thanks for indulging me, @sfdcfox!